# unable to get response of ajax request in symfony2

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony

I am new to symfony2. Basically I want to send a variable `name` to a file named `sub.html.php`.  I am making  an ajax request as following :

```
function onsub()
    {
        alert(document.getElementById('source').value);
        var http=new XMLHttpRequest();
        var name="rohit";
        http.open("POST", {{path('task1')}}, false);


        http.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
        alert(http.status);
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) 
            {

                alert('i m back');
            }
            else
            {
                alert('sorry');

            }
        }  

        http.send();
        return false;
    }
```

I have defined the route of `task1` as follow:

```
task1:
    pattern:    /task1/
    defaults:   {_controller:AcmeTaskBundle:Task:task1}
```

and in TaskController I have defined task1Action as follow:

```
public function task1Action()
    {
    return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:sub.html.php');
    }
```

but I am unable to call the sub.html.php file anyhow. How can I call this file?

Comment: you don't "call" sub.html.php, you make a request to a URL, which gets mapped to a controller and an action. Is your `task1` route exposed to the client-side?

Comment: yep I have done like this. when I am calling the file like this: http.open("POST", "{{path('task1')}}?field="+name, false); then in http.responseText, it is returning the complete code of the sub.html.php file.If I want to send the data to the controller then how can I do this?

Comment: to what controller? its already passing through your `TaskController` --> `task1Action()`

Comment: yeah I am getting the data in TaskController. I want to send this data from one action to another one, how can I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can forward the request from the `TaskController::task1Action()` like so...

```
$response = $this->forward('VendorOtherBundleName:ControllerName:ActionName', array(
    'some_variable'  => $value
));
```

You can read more [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding)

Comment: when I am adding this thing then, I am getting the ajax response as 500